# React stop other events on that element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, events

I have a volume element that shows the volume bar when the user hovers over it. This all works great in desktop. However to get the same functionality on mobile, the user has clicks on the volume element which also toggles the mute click event.

I am wanting to stop that mute event when the user clicks (i.e taps) on that element on mobile.

I don't want to modify the Mute or VolumeBar classes to fix this because these are generic classes in my library that the developer uses.

https://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/2145/

- Actual: The mute click event gets fired and the volume bar opens.
- Expected: The mute click event **doesn't** gets fired and the volume bar opens.

Open the console -> go into mobile view (CTRL + SHIFT + M on chrome) -> click the volume button and observe the console logs.

**What I have tried:**

Using `volumeControlOnClick` to stop propogation when the volume bar's height is 0 (i.e not visible), this does not cancel the onClick though.

**What I want:**

To cancel the mute click event if the user clicks on the volume icon for the first time in mobile. Instead it should only show the volume bar.

```
const volumeControlOnClick = (e) => {
  const volumeBarContainer =
    e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling.querySelector('.jp-volume-bar-container');
  /* Stop propogation is for mobiles to stop
    triggering mute when showing volume bar */
  if (volumeBarContainer.clientHeight === 0) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("stop propogation")
  }
};

class Volume extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};
  }
    render() {
    return (
        <div className="jp-volume-container">
        <Mute onTouchStart={volumeControlOnClick}><i className="fa fa-volume-up" /></Mute>
        <div className="jp-volume-controls">
          <div className="jp-volume-bar-container">
            <VolumeBar />
          </div>
         </div>
       </div>
    );
  }
};

class Mute extends React.Component {
    render() {
    return (
      <button className="jp-mute" onClick={() => console.log("mute toggled")} onTouchStart={this.props.onTouchStart}>
        {this.props.children}
      </button>
    );
  }
};

class VolumeBar extends React.Component {
    render() {
    return (
        <div className="jp-volume-bar" onClick={() => console.log("bar moved")}>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
};

React.render(<Volume />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: `.preventDefault` on the touch event, fire a new event which will cause the thing you want (e.g. mouseenter), or, add a ~`200ms` delay after a touch event where all click events are ignored

Comment: Tried adding `.preventDefault` to the `volumeControlOnClick`. This didn't stop the click event from firing though.

How would I add the delay?

Comment: I'm not seeing the "mute" behavior you describe on Android Chrome or Desktop Chrome. Is this an iOS problem?

Comment: @Matt It happens on desktop chrome mobile view. This isn't an IOS specific problem. The problem is that the click event fires on mobile when I want it to just show the volume bar

Comment: Ok - so there is no visual indication that mute has been clicked?

Comment: @Matt I used console.log to show it visually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I ended up with. It works because `onTouchStart` is always calld before `onClick` if it's a touch event and if not's then the custom logic gets called anyway. It also fires before the hover has happened. This preserves the :hover event. `e.preventDefault()` did not.

```
let isVolumeBarVisible;

const onTouchStartMute = e => (
  isVolumeBarVisible = e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling
    .querySelector('.jp-volume-bar-container').clientHeight > 0
);

const onClickMute = () => () => {
  if (isVolumeBarVisible !== false) {
    // Do custom mute logic
  }
  isVolumeBarVisible = undefined;
};

<Mute
  aria-haspopup onTouchStart={onTouchStartMute}
  onClick={onClickMute}
>
  <i className="fa">{/* Icon set in css*/}</i>
</Mute>
```

Comment: How is this different from my first suggestion to you? You are using a flag based on the fact "touchStart" fires before "click". Exactly what I did and you said you couldn't modify the Mute class...

Comment: @FelipeT. I added it because the logic is different, which is what stackoverflow wants because this is the complete answer. I'll give you the bounty if no better answers come.

I am not modifying the Mute class. This all sits within Volume class I just omitted redundant code from the example. I'd rather not overwrite the onClick handler but I don't see another way.

Comment: The logic is the same (use a flag since touchStart fires first). You changed the handler in the Mute class exactly like I did using a "if" statement (look at my code before any editions to the answer). Then, you said: "I don't want to modify the Mute class onClick handler to fix this"  Feb 19 at 18:35. No need for the bounty or to tell me what Stackoverflow wants.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use a flag to indicate you were in a touch event before being in your mouse event, as long as you are using **bubble phase**. So attach a listener to your container element like this:

```
let isTouch = false;

const handleContainerClick = () => isTouch = false;

const handleMuteClick = () => {
  if (isTouch == false) {
    console.log("mute toggled");
  }
};

const volumeControlOnClick = () => {
  isTouch = true;
};

class Volume extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="jp-volume-container" onClick={handleContainerClick}>
        <Mute onTouchStart={volumeControlOnClick} onClick={handleMuteClick}><i className="fa fa-volume-up" /></Mute>
        <div className="jp-volume-controls">
          <div className="jp-volume-bar-container">
            <VolumeBar />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

class Mute extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button className="jp-mute" onTouchStart={this.props.onTouchStart} onClick={this.props.onClick}>
        {this.props.children}
      </button>
    );
  }
};

class VolumeBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="jp-volume-bar" onClick={() => console.log("bar moved")}>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
};

render(<Volume />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

If you are not using bubble phase so you can register a timeout of 100ms with the same logic above, where after 100ms you make your flag variable false again. Just add to your touchStart handler:

```
setTimeout(() => {isTouch = false}, 100);
```

**EDIT:** Even though touch events are supposed to be passive by default in Chrome 56, you call preventDefault() from a touchEnd event to prevent the click handler from firing. So, if you can't modify the click handler of your Mute class in any way, but you can add a touchEnd event, than you could do:

```
const handleTouchEnd = (e) => e.preventDefault();

const volumeControlOnClick = () => console.log("volumeControlOnClick");

class Volume extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="jp-volume-container">
        <Mute onTouchStart={volumeControlOnClick} onTouchEnd={handleTouchEnd}><i className="fa fa-volume-up" /></Mute>
        <div className="jp-volume-controls">
          <div className="jp-volume-bar-container">
            <VolumeBar />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

class Mute extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button className="jp-mute" onTouchStart={this.props.onTouchStart} onTouchEnd={this.props.onTouchEnd} onClick={() => console.log("mute toggled")}>
        {this.props.children}
      </button>
    );
  }
};

class VolumeBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="jp-volume-bar" onClick={() => console.log("bar moved")}>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
};

render(<Volume />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: I don't want to modify the Mute class onClick handler to fix this this. The class will be used in a wide range of scenario's, some where the developer will not be using the volume bar hover. The fix should come solely from Volume class.

I could overwrite the onClick handler but I was hoping there was a better way than this.

Comment: Can't you pass the onClick handler from above like you are doing with touchStart?

Comment: I'd have to overwrite a bunch of logic already in the Mute click handler.

Comment: Basically, you would need an "if" statement, but if you can't change the handler too I don't see another way  off the top of my head.

Comment: @MartinMazzaDawson I added a new possibility to my answer. You can call preventDefault from a touchEnd event.

Comment: Thanks for another answer. This has prevented the click event from firing which is good. But now the volume bar doesn't slide up or down which I need. It's stopped :hover working.

Comment: If your ":hover" is not working when you are not with the devtools touch screen emulation enabled then it is something else in your code. Here works perfectly. And just to clarify, of course, hover (or mouseOver) will not work on a touchscreen only device.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 render() {
        return (
      <div className="jp-volume-container" onClick={handleContainerClick}>
        <Mute onTouchStart={volumeControlOnClick} onClick={handleMuteClick}><i className="fa fa-volume-up" /></Mute>
        <div className="jp-volume-controls">
          <div className="jp-volume-bar-container">
            <VolumeBar />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

class Mute extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button className="jp-mute" onTouchStart={this.props.onTouchStart} onClick={this.props.onClick}>
        {this.props.children}
      </button>
    );
  }
};

class VolumeBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="jp-volume-bar" onClick={() => console.log("bar moved")}>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
};

render(<Volume />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: Where does handleContainerClick come from? Use JSfiddle